# prevent indentation of a paragraph

Tags: lyx, indentation

In Lyx, by default most paragraphs are indented (except at beginning of section and after lists). How can I cancel the indentation for specific paragraphs?

Comment: On a case-by-case basis, you could insert an ERT with `\noindent` at the start of the paragraph.

Comment: You can, but you should ask yourself why you'd want to do it, to begin with. I see no reason whatsoever for not indenting the start of a new paragraph (except after titles). You *can* indent the text after a list, just leave an empty line. If LyX doesn't allow it, it's another reason why not using it.

Comment: To have a consistent appearance of your document, you could change the indentation for the whole document under "Document > Settings > Text Layout" or use vertical skips instead...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right click in the paragraph, click Paragraph Settings, uncheck *Indent Paragraph* in the lower left corner of the dialog box. (This does the same as Werner's comment, `\noindent` is added to the LaTeX source, but you do not need the ERT.)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I didn't want the identation for texts coming right after an equation. I was following the approach suggested by Torbjørn T., but it was kinda cumbersome in my case, since I had a lot of equations, and I didn't find any keyboard shortcuts for doing it.

However, I've just noticed that if you continue to write right after the equation (without pressing the Enter key) the line will continue as if it were part of the same paragraph, which was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Good point! This is actually the correct method in that context, as it avoids starting a new paragraph altogether.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Is there a means of defaulting all paragraphs to be non-indented?