# How to stop LyX from indenting the start of every paragraph?

Tags: lyx, indentation, paragraphs

I can select the paragraph > Right-click > Paragraph settings > Uncheck "Indent Paragraph" > "OK".

But now new paragraphs still have the same indentation. How do I stop this completely (other than always having to do the above for every new paragraph)?

[image]

(I followed this: [prevent indentation of a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100908/) but my goal is to permanently stop the indentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document > Settings > Text Layout > Indentation > Choose "Custom", and enter 0 > "OK"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the setting mentioned by `user182601`, we can change the LaTeX code, either from the preamble using `\usepackage{parskip}` or insert inline code [Ctrl+L] and `noident` (for a specific paragraph).

Credit `doncherry` and `Carsten Hagemann`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27807/208394